# im trying to name a file "Distributor.js" in my node project using atom

Tags: node.js, git, atom-editor, atlassian-sourcetree

im trying to name a file "Distributor.js" in my node project using atom. it creates the file but then its not visible in the sourcetree for me to commit and push it. why is this?

Answer (score -1):

i checked the .gitignore file and found the dist in the ignore list. that is why i was unable to commit/push the file to bucket.